# Accessing redux dispatch from deeply nested components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using react-redux with the  components. It passes dispatch as a prop into my top level component, but i'm having trouble accessing it from deeply nested (and some other more complexly mounted) components. What is the best way to access dispatch from any component? Do I need to pass it manually as a prop to every component I'd like to use it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `connect` on components even if they are bellow some already connected components.

Comment: Oh how embarrassing. Yes I realize now that you need to `connect` the component for dispatch to get passed through. Silly me. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! One has to start by something!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `connect` everywhere around you can just explicitly import store and dispatch on it: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html